# C# running configuration differ

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, release

I have a wpf application and i want to **upload** some data to a **sql server** on a **click** of a button:

```
private void Submit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("helo");
    List<string> list = new();
    foreach (var element in StackPanel1.Children)
    {
    list.Add(s.GetResult());
    }

    MySqlConnection connection = new(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new($"INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (\"{list[0]}\", \"{list[1]}\", \"{list[2]}\", \"{list[3]}\");", connection);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Successful execution, rows affected: {cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()}");
    connection.Close();
}
```

If i run the program in debug mode everything is working perfectly fine but when i run it in release mode and i click the button nothing happens, not even the `Debug.WriteLine("helo");` runs.

Comment: "not even the Debug.WriteLine("helo"); runs" - well no, you're running in Release mode, which means presumably you haven't got the DEBUG symbol defined. I wouldn't *expect* `Debug.WriteLine` to do anything. But the rest of the code should work. (Admittedly I'd strongly advise you to use parameterised SQL instead of your current code that's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks...)

Comment: Yes, don't expect debug messages in release assembly. Instead check the target table for update. What's 's'?

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid this is a perfectly valid answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [System.Diagnostics.Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug?view=net-7.0):

> In Visual Studio C# and Visual Basic projects, by default, the DEBUG
> conditional compilation symbol is defined for debug builds,...

Placing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` inside a `Debug.WriteLine` statement is the source of your issue. You also should use [using statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using) for anything that has a *Dispose* method.